# Name error: variable is not defined

Tags: python, python-2.7, input, nameerror

I'm trying to create a really basic program with Python 2.7.10 as displayed below:

```
Colour = input("What's your favourite colour?")
print (Colour)
```

After I answer my question, say I answer "Blue", I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Python27/Practise.py", line 1, in <module>
Colour=input("What's your favourite colour?")
File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'Blue' is not defined
```

I know this may seem like a noob question, but if I could get your help on how to fix this, that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

In Python2, `input` tries to take whatever it is given and **immediately process it as if it were real Python code**. This is called an `eval` and is a huge security risk in production code (not so much when you're just playing around trying to learn).

From the [Python 2 docs on input](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#input):

> Equivalent to `eval(raw_input(prompt))`.

To avoid this, replace your `input` calls with [`raw_input`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input) which will return a string instead.